# How to display median values of each group on a barplot using Seaborn

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, bar-chart

I have a house pricing dataset, And I plotted a bar plot of houses sold in different years, what I want to do is display the median prices of each years. Something like [image: this] , Any idea how I can accomplish this? I cant find anything related to this, for reference  [here's the dataset link](https://www.kaggle.com/c/house-prices-advanced-regression-techniques/data)

EDIT:- Here's what I have achieved so far using seaborn

```
data2['LotFrontage'].replace(np.nan,0 , inplace=True)
data2['Alley'].replace(np.nan, 'NA', inplace=True)
data2['PoolQC'].replace(np.nan, 'NA', inplace=True)
data2['Fence'].replace(np.nan, 'NA', inplace=True)
data2['MiscFeature'].replace(np.nan, 'NA', inplace=True)
data2['FireplaceQu'].replace(np.nan, 'NA', inplace=True)
data2['GarageType'].replace(np.nan, 'NA', inplace=True)
data2['MasVnrType'].replace(np.nan, "NA",inplace=True)
data2['MasVnrArea'].replace(np.nan, 0, inplace=True)
data2['BsmtQual'].replace(np.nan, 'NA', inplace=True)
data2['BsmtCond'].replace(np.nan,'NA',inplace=True)
data2['BsmtExposure'].replace(np.nan,'NA',inplace=True)
data2['BsmtFinType1'].replace(np.nan,'NA',inplace=True)
data2['BsmtFinType2'].replace(np.nan,'NA',inplace=True)
data2['Electrical'].replace(np.nan,"NA", inplace=True)
data2['GarageYrBlt'].replace(np.nan,"NA", inplace=True)
data2['GarageFinish'].replace(np.nan,"NA", inplace=True)
data2['GarageQual'].replace(np.nan,"NA", inplace=True)
data2['GarageCond'].replace(np.nan,"NA", inplace=True)
```

this is the dataset pre-processing for anyone who wants to give it a try and I tried to plot out the values I needed with a bar plot.

```
sns.barplot(data=data2,x=data2['YrSold'].value_counts().index,y=data2['YrSold'].value_counts())
```

[image: this] this is the output I am getting, any idea how I can also aggregate the average sale prices on top of it ?

Comment: Did you try any code yourself and if so what did you get? We're generally looking for a minimal, complete and verifiable problem which you can find more about here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Yea I did try but I cant really figure out how to add a third variable (selling prices) to the bar plot since my x and y are the years and # of houses sold.

Comment: Right, but if you don't show what you've done, you're basically asking folks to go get the data, install it, somehow intuit what you've done and what your problem is ... and then fix it. So, show your work and what efforts you've made.

Comment: yea you are  right that's a bit presumptuous of me I have edited the post with my starting work

Comment: Side note: you can replace those NaNs more concisely with `.fillna(0, inplace=True)` and `.fillna('NA', inplace=True)`

Answer (score 1):

Seaborn is designed for quick and good-looking charts without having to do all of the stuff with matplotlib which can be a pain.

The problem you're having is, being a limited set of matplotlib, seaborn doesn't do everything and you've bumped up what can be done with seaborn out of the box. The good thing is seaborn can take matplotlib commands to override these limitations.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

sns.set_theme()
df = pd.read_csv('data/train.csv')

plt.figure(figsize=(17,8))
chart = sns.barplot(data=df,x=df['YrSold'].value_counts().index,y=df['YrSold'].value_counts())

for p in chart.patches:
    chart.annotate("%.0f" % p.get_height(), (p.get_x() + p.get_width() / 2., p.get_height()),
    ha='center', va='center', fontsize=13, color='black', xytext=(0, 10),
    textcoords='offset points')
```

Which gets you about what you're looking for.

[image]

You'll also notice I took out the ci interval. I think that's confusing for this sort of graph. A violin plot would be a better choice in this case.

Comment: Not what I'm looking for, it's just displaying the y value of each point on top of the bar, My question how can I display the average price of all these houses sold on a yearly basis on top of each bar ( which represents the number of houses sold for that particular year).

Answer (score -1):

```
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
j = sns.barplot(x='your_x', y='your_y', data=your_data, estimator=np.median)
```